# org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value 'java.lang.String' to 'java.lang.Class' spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat

I dont know why  spring is giving me this error when I launch my application. I have defined the java class in the package and calling it in the xml file through bean injection.

This is the bean injection

```
 <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value type="java.lang.Class">main.com.mpakhomov.chat.domain.User</value>
                <value type="java.lang.Class">main.com.mpakhomov.chat.domain.ChatMessage</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">${hibernate.connection.pool_size}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

this is the complete stacktrace of the error that am i having when I try to launch my application.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Class'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [main.com.mpakhomov.chat.domain.User]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:39)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:187)
```

Assuming the class is defined in the package, please what could be wrong when I launch my application?

Comment: it is just that the version on your spring doesn't comply with your hibernate version.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are wrong when you declare the package of the entities:

If your package is com.mpakhomov.*, you should replace

```
<list>
    <value type="java.lang.Class">main.com.mpakhomov.chat.domain.User</value>
    <value type="java.lang.Class">main.com.mpakhomov.chat.domain.ChatMessage</value>
</list>
```

with

```
<list>
    <value type="java.lang.Class">com.mpakhomov.chat.domain.User</value>
    <value type="java.lang.Class">com.mpakhomov.chat.domain.ChatMessage</value>
</list>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you needn't specify the type attribute for the value tag. My guess is that the value tag is expecting a type String and you are trying to convert to `java.lang.class` and it is causing an IllegalArgumentException. So the argument type is wrong here. You can see the error in the following line.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Class'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Try removing the type attribute as follows

```
<list>
    <value>main.com.mpakhomov.chat.domain.User</value>
    <value>main.com.mpakhomov.chat.domain.ChatMessage</value>
</list>
```

Also take a look into spring documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M2/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html). They are not passing any type attribute with the value tag. The following is the example they used in the documentation.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
   <property name="annotatedClasses">
     <list>
       <value>test.package.Foo</value>
       <value>test.package.Bar</value>
     </list>
   </property>
 </bean>
```